# An event which fires when each image or script or other item is downloaded

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, mshtml, twebbrowser

I would need to examine HTML into `TWebBrowser` control which is loading for invalid links such as the ones beginning with `\\` (UNC path) (e.g. `<img src="\\some\path">`) and strip these out or cancel loading (replace the URL with blank string for example).

At the moment, when such links are found, MSHTML automatically replaces them with `file://some\path` and then attempts to load them locally and that takes a long time (about 15 seconds) before it gives up. What I would like is to give up/cancel such loading in the first place.

I am using MSHTML based wrapper (`TEmbeddedWB`) but if there is a solution without it I don't care as long as it works.

Comment: AFAIK, MSHTML does not provide events on a per-item event. You should fixup the HTML before you load it into the browser in the first place.

Comment: @remy-lebeau So in other words, I need a HTML parser separate from MSHTML?

Comment: For each resource `OnBeforeNavigate2` event is triggered.

Comment: @Victoria: no, it is not.  It is only triggered when the main document is being navigated to.  It is not triggered for each external resource that the document refers to. I tested it, MSHTML does not trigger `OnBeforeNavigate2` for individual images and such.

Comment: @Victoria It triggers for top-level documents, such as main HTML, frames, iframes and so on. Also tested.